# Why my handleChange method does not format the user's input with decimal numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to format my user's input data to the following format `XX.xxxxxx` range using the method below.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  let dataFormatted = e.target.value < 1 || e.target.value >= 10 ? (+e.target.value).toFixed(6) : '0'+(+e.target.value).toFixed(6)
  console.log("dataFormatted: ", dataFormatted)
};
```

The method works fine without the decimal numbers because it converts my user's input to the correct format. However, it doesn't seems to work with decimal numbers. Every time when I type in any number with decimal and hits the decimal key in the keyboard, the output I am getting is `0NaN`

For example, the following input works as I can see the output convert into the proper format:

```
9 => 09.000000
2 => 02.000000
12 => 12.000000
```

but the ones where I enter decimal numbers returns `0NaN`, and the output that I should expect to see are the followings:

```
0.060 => 00.060000
10.4960 => 10.496000
1.99 => 01.990000
29.666666 => 29.666666
```

here is the complete code:

```
<Input
  id="location-latitude-control"
  label="Latitude"
  title="Required: Latitude"
  name="location.latitude"
  value={location.latitude}
  type="number"
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
/>

handleChange = (e) => {
  if (isNaN(+e.target.value)) return;
    let dataFormatted =
      e.target.value < 1 || e.target.value >= 10
        ? (+e.target.value).toFixed(6)
        : "0" + (+e.target.value).toFixed(6);
    this.handleChangeLatitude(e.target.name, e.target.value)
};

handleChangeLatitude = (name, value) => {
  this.props.saveLocationEntity({
    dataPath: name,
    value: value,
  });
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  saveLocationEntity: (payload) => {
    return dispatch({
      type: SAVE_LOCATION_ENTITY,
      data: payload,
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Don't see any problem while you typing numbers. You better add `type=number` for you `input` element. https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-platform-2w2wp?file=/index.js

Comment: @DennisVash I provided the type="number" to the field element and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you open the sandbox? Where is the problem?

Comment: yes, I tested the sandbox and I can see that it's working there fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your handleChange is running as an onChange handler, which means it will run on *every* key press within your input.  When you press `.` as the first key within the input it attempts to run your code and of course `+(.)` results in NaN.

Just don't run your code if the result is NaN:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  if (isNaN((+e.target.value))) {
    return;
  }
  let dataFormatted = e.target.value < 1 || e.target.value >= 10 ? (+e.target.value).toFixed(6) : '0'+(+e.target.value).toFixed(6)
  console.log("dataFormatted: ", dataFormatted)
};
```

Comment: I tried the above code and that fixed the `NaN` issue, but still it does not allow me to enter any number to the field after I press decimal. For example, if I type `2` then I can see it gets formatted to `02.000000` but if I try to type `4.5` then the field only displays `04.000000`

Comment: It must be something else in your code.  The results are fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/formatdecimal-jvpy4?file=/index.js

Comment: Are you trying to use that value in state and then setting the input value attribute to the state variable corresponding to your formatted data?

Comment: I just updated my post with the complete code at the bottom of the post. Can you please review and let me know why it's not working with the code that I have?

Comment: Yeah, it's because of the fact that you're using a controlled input with `value={location.latitude}`.    You could remove the value attribute from the input or handle the formatting onSubmit of the form or onBlur of the input instead of onChange.

Comment: Can you please help me with onBlur method?

Comment: I updated the codesandbox with an example that uses a controlled input (where the value is set onChange) and an onBlur handler that formats the code when you click outside the input. As an alternative example.

Comment: That worked like a charm now. Thank you so much! I am really grateful for your help.